# Xcode doesn't allow to add internacionalization

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, xcode5

I have a project in XCode 5 (Target iOS 7.0). I removed "Base Localization" and my Main.Storyboard. Then, i restores my Main.Storyboard, but XCode doesn´t allow me to add any localization. Do someone know this problem?

I tried the checkbox "Use Base Internacionalization", the "+" button. When I tried to add, there is no "resource file" and "Reference Language". When I press finish, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im my experience, Base internationalization just confuses the issue of localization. My localized apps don't use it. Just create a Localizable.strings file ([SmoothLocalize](http://smoothlocalize.com/) has a good tutorial [HERE](http://smoothlocalize.com/tutorial1.php)) in English, then follow the tutorial for adding further languages. English will be the default.